# tableofcontentsの内容でページ番号をsectionまでにしたい。

Tags: latex

Windows環境でTexStudio使っています。
LaTeXは、出力結果が便利だから使っている程度で深い造詣はありません。

tableofcontentsは、subsectionの項目まで作られますが
この時。ページ番号はsectionまでにするという事は、可能でしょうか。

こんな感じにしたいのです。

```
第1章 aaaaa　　　　　　　　 3
　1.1.　bbbbb..............3
    1.1.1. ccccc
    1.1.2. ddddd
    1.1.3. eeeee
　1.2. fffff...............5
    1.2.1. ggggg
    1.2.2. hhhhh
```

Comment: やりたいことは、目次のページ番号の表示を自由にしたいだけですので。パッケージ等で同様のことが実現できればそれでも構いません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tocloft](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)パッケージをロードして、`\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}`とのコマンドで設定できます。

例えば、このサンプルドキュメント

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection A}

\subsection{Subsection B}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

の出力結果のtableofcontentsは以下のようになります。

[image: toc]

項目はsubsectionまで、ページ番号はsectionまで入っているから、質問者の要件に合っていると思います。

Comment: 解決手順もシンプルでとても助かりました。　：）